# Canyon Endurace CF SL Disc: 7.0 vs 8.0

Tags: disc-brake, carbon, seatpost, road, comfort

**Mission:** On the market for a new road bicycle. Since May 2020 I stepped up my cycling and will probably at least triple the yearly kilometres (3k?). So I want to treat myself and I decided to invest a max of 2500€ in a new carbon road bike.

**Brand:** I had very good experience with Canyon so far (a 2015 Endurace AL and a 2018 Grand Canyon AL). So direct to consumer paranoia aside, that's best bang for buck you can get (anyone argues differently?). So that's Canyon (carbon) I guess.

**Bike type:** My riding style is far from aggressive, currently on rides of 50km+ I start to feel slightly uncomfortable. So one of the first thing I need the bike to be is comfy. So that's a Canyon Endurace.

**Brakes:** Had a talk with a friend who does a lot of biking and he assured me the disc is worth all the cost and the weight it brings. I guess I'm happy with feeling more secure on long descents, even if I had problems with a bent rotor on my MTB. So that's Canyon Endurace Disc.

**Price range:** This being said I see two options: Canyon Endurace CF SL Disc 7.0 or 8.0. The difference is 500€ which I would be willing to spend if I find an adequate rationale. And this is where my question pops up: is the 8.0 version worth the 500€ more?

The difference boils down to (left the 7.0, 8.0 on the right):

- Fork: F38 vs FK0086
- Groupset: 105 vs Ultegra
- Wheel set: DT Swiss E1850 vs E1800
- Tyres: Continental Grand Prix SL vs 5000
- Saddle: Selle Italia X3 vs Fizik Aliante R5
- Seat post: SP0043 vs S15
- Weight: 8,39 vs 8,10

So what I see above is a higher grade groupset, 300gr less bike weight and that weird seat post which is the S15. The majority of the reviews for the S15 are quite positive but it is more a complicated part than the standard carbon seat post. Simplicity usually wins it for me. Could it be that more comfy (and I love comfort) to offset the additional maintenance it should bring?

Any thoughts/help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this question got downvoted. May I know why please? The first part is an introduction as to why I'm choosing a specific make/model, the second part is the specific question about the worthiness to spend a specific sum of money on certain features. Please provide feedback and I'll try to improve my question.

Comment: Your question violates two explicit off topic rules. Product recommendations are hard off-topic here. Whether one model is worth 500€ more than another is opinion based, which is also off-topic. Some people downvote rather then voting to close which leads to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Far be it from me to discourage anyone from buying a new bike, but you might find that changing just the saddle and tires on your bike, and maybe getting a fitting, will be all you need to make it more comfortable. And putting in longer rides so you get acclimated.

Comment: I've made clear my rationale for purchasing a new carbon frame bike. In my current situation it should serve as a motivator for continuing the steady progress. The investment is not an issue in this case. I guess the same applies for a large slice of weekend warriors. Thanks for the feedback but I cannot accept this as an answer.